# How to add ID and class in nav menu walker?

Tags: menus, walker

I would like to set up a custom walker that produces the following output:

```
 <div id="navbarHolder">
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="nav_about" href="#about">ABOUT<span class="m_w">ABOUT</span><span class="m_r">ABOUT</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="nav_work" href="#work">WORK<span class="m_w">WORK</span><span class="m_r">WORK</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="nav_projects" href="#projects">Projects<span class="m_w">Projects</span><span class="m_r">Projects</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="nav_contact" href="#contact">Contact<span class="m_w">Contact</span><span class="m_r">Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- end div #navbarHolder -->
```

My current walker code is as follows:

```
<?php
class MFC_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
     * @param object $args
     */
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;           

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

                // new addition for active class on the a tag
                if(in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
                    $attributes .= ' class="active"';
                }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you would like to have? Must the output be exactly as demonstrated (i.e., no default menu classes and the like), or would you just like to have the link IDs and the custom title/content (with the two spans) as demonstrated?

Comment: Trying to figure out this same thing myself right now